# POS Testing automation

Tags: automated-testing

We are using XPIENT POS system. We have a deck of regression scripts that could be a good candidate for automation. However, I am not aware of any tools or any technology that could be used to automate tests for POS system - XPIENT IRIS. Need some pointers to get started with POC.

I would be highly obliged if I could get some inputs from experts or who have already been automation testing POS

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance!